# Select NUKE nodes, where class of a nodes starts with string "OFXuk"

Tags: python, nuke

Any idea how to create a script that can select nodes of same class that starts with class  name "OFXuk"

for example if i have list of nodes, with different class as below

```
OFXuk.ab.cdef.ghi_node1
OFXuk.ab.cdef.ghi_node2
OFXuk.ab.cdef.ghi_node3
```

I want to select all three nodes by their common starting string "OFXuk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try the following code snippet for selecting `Furnace`-class nodes:

[image]

```
import nuke

for index in nuke.allNodes():
    nodeClass = index.Class()

    if nodeClass.__contains__("OFXuk"):
        index.setSelected(True)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wooohoooo!! 

It Worked!!